# Implement Zoom(using UI Canvas) in Unity 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to implement as showed in the below image in 2D game, I can find so many tutorials for 3D like mini map concept but for 2D i couldn't find anything. In my game i want to show a secondary [image]
camera as in below image and also i need to zoom the content that will show through it. I developed one concept but it can be done with sprites or with Canvas in World Space mode. So you can see
they won't resize or positioned according to the screen resolution. If you guys have any idea how to do this task,it will be very helpful for me. And i also tried with depth mask shader .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be missing the point here, but why can't you just use a secondary camera?

Answer (score 0):

**Use a camera with target texture**

Follow my tutorial here: [Particles with Dynamic Text](https://youtu.be/E2AA-EgjbIw?list=PL7g66HK9Kg-gJGsCWQPx1VJs3c-glpwkJ)  but **disregard** the parts about the particle system, they are irrelevant for you.

Once you've made a material, stop following the tutorial, and instead:

Create a sprite renderer on a canvas that is "Screen Space - Overlay" and set the material to be the one that you created.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i know this concept, i saw so many people used it for the implementation of MiniMap view in unity 3D games. My exact scenario is that i want to place a UI image(Which will be circle typed) on top of the camera which will then be looked as circle view and then i will zoom the mini camera by changing its size in camera settings.